# MVT on continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function such that $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$.

Prove that $\exists c \in (0,1)$ such that
$$ f(c) = \frac{1-c}{1+c}$$

I still don't get the idea behind it. I tried
$\exists c \in (0,1)$ such that $f(c)= \frac{1}{2}$

We have then $f'(c)=1$ and the tangent at the point $c$ is expressed :

$ f'(x)= f'(c)(x-c) + f(c)$

$f'(x)=(x-c) + \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: What they ask is something different. For example, if $f(x)=x$, you need to find the value for which $x=(1-x)/(1+x)$. For this particular function, the solution is $c=\sqrt 2 -1$. You don't need to find $c$ for any function, just need to show that it exists.

Comment: A minor point:  If you are working with a function that you know is continuous but don't know is differentiable, you probably want to consider the Intermediate Value Theorem, not the Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$g(x):=f(x)-\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ is continuous and satisfies $g(0)=-1$ and $g(1)=1$, so by a certain theorem...

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=x+(1+x)f(x)$. Then $g(0)=f(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1+2f(1)=3$. So, for some $c\in(0,1)$, $g(c)=1$. But$$g(c)=1\iff c+(1+c)f(c)=1\iff f(c)=\frac{1-c}{1+c}.$$